# setState inside useEffect not working on First Render in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, use-effect, use-state

I'm building a ReactJS Component that uses React Awesome Slider.
What I'm trying to create is a slider with a description div under it, which changes the text then I change the Slide.

Now, I found a way to make it work but I have a problem with the setState of an object, here is the code.

**SLIDER:**

```
const AutoplaySlider = withAutoplay(AwesomeSlider);

const StaticSlider = ({slider}) => {
    var images = "";
    var length=0;
   
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState([]);
   
    switch (slider) {

        case 'portfolio_sviluppo_software':

            images = portfolio_description.sviluppo_software;
            length= portfolio_description.sviluppo_software.length;
          
            break;
        case 'portfolio_domotica':

            images = portfolio_description.domotica;
            length= portfolio_description.domotica.length;
            
            break;
        case 'portfolio_digital_signage':

            images = portfolio_description.digital_signage;
            length= portfolio_description.digital_signage.length;
           
            break;
        case 'portfolio_ricerca_e_sviluppo':

            images = portfolio_description.ricerca_e_sviluppo;
            length= portfolio_description.ricerca_e_sviluppo.length;
           
            break;
    }
   
    useEffect(
        () => {
            setTitle(
                images.map(
                    (slide) => (slide.title)
                )
            );
            setDescription(
                images.map(
                    (desc) => (desc.data)
                )
            );
            }, [images]
            
    );
   
    return(
        <div>
            <AutoplaySlider
                play={true}
                cancelOnInteraction={true}
                interval={0}
                onTransitionStart={slide => setCurrent(slide.nextIndex)}
                className="sliderHome"
                >
                {images.map((image, index) => {
                        
                    let src = "/image/slider/portfolio/"+image.image;
                    //console.log(src);
                    return (
                        <div key={index} data-src={src}>
                        </div>
                    );
                
                })}
            </AutoplaySlider>
            <GalleryCaption selected={current} title={title} description={description} area={slider}/>
        </div>
)
};

export default StaticSlider;
```

**DESCRIPTION GENERATOR**

```
const GalleryCaption = ({ selected = 0, title = [], description= [], area = 0 }) => {
  const formattedIndex = selected + 1;
  var title = title[selected];
  var data = description[selected];
  return (
    <div className="containerDivDescriptionPortflio">
      <div className="DivDescriptionPortflio">
          <p id ={"description_portfolio_"+area} className="paragDescriptionPortflio" >
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <hr></hr>
            {
                data.map((val) => (
                 <div className="rowDescriptionPortfolio">
                   <div className="divIndexPortfolio" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: val.index }} >

                   </div>
                   <div className="divTextPortfolio" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: val.text }} >
                     
                   </div>
                 </div>
            ))}
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>

  );
};

export default GalleryCaption;
```

**OBJECT EXAMPLE**

```
{
            "title":"text",
            "data":[
                {
                    "index":"text",
                    "text": "text"
                },
                {
                    "index":"text",
                    "text": "text"
                }
            ],
            "image": "folder/image.jpg"
        },
```

(This is an element of an array of this kind of object)
Now the main problem is that if inside the use effect I only call the setTitle function all works as it should, but if I use also the setDescription all just stop working. I didn't get a specific error, but I get a white screen.

ERROR THAT I GET

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `PortfolioArea`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at PortfolioArea (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1618:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4509:78
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:177110:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:177043:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:176523:5)
    at App
    at AppProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3289:5)

Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

Please update the following components: AwesomeSlider
The above error occurred in the <GalleryCaption> component:
    
        at GalleryCaption (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:973:5)
        at div
        at StaticSlider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3049:5)
        at div
        at PortfolioArea (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1618:5)
        at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4510:78
        at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:177111:5)
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:177044:15)
        at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:176524:5)
        at App
        at AppProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3290:5)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.`

I've tried to change the useEffect second parameters to null and also to use a unique state for every parameter, but the problem seems to be that every time I try to set a state with an object inside the useEffect, on the first render I always get a null value inside that state.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I added the error in the edit, but I'm not sure it can help, it's a generic error @tbjgolden

Comment: it mentions an above error, could you post that above error?

Comment: Added the code in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in `StaticSlider`, since `images` and `length` are calculated based on `slider` prop, I suggest using `useMemo()` to calculate them per `slider` change, instead of reassigning the values to the `var` variables, which is not how it should be done in React and invites bugs to come.

```
const StaticSlider = ({slider}) => {
    const images = useMemo(
      () => {
        // calculate and return images value
        // with `switch`
        switch (slider) {
          // ...
          default:
            return [];
        }
      },
      [slider]
    );

    const length = useMemo(
      () => {
        // calculate and return length value
        // with `switch`
        switch (slider) {
          // ...
          default:
            return 0;
        }
      },
      [slider]
    );
```

Please note that your current `switch` block does not have a `default` case, you should consider returning a default case with initial values for `images` and `length`.

Also note that the initial assignment of `images` is `images = ""` which would make it a `string`, but inside `setDescription()` you are calling `images.map()` which is an array method, so it won't work at the **initial render** of the component when `images` is an empty string. I think this is what causes the bug.

`images = []` or `default: return []` for images inside `switch` statement should be better.

Lastly I think you can consider using a condition check inside `useEffect()` to only `setState` on `title` and `description` when `images` is already populated (has length).

```
    useEffect(
        () => {
          if (images.length) {
            setTitle(
                images.map(
                    (slide) => (slide.title)
                )
            );

            setDescription(
                images.map(
                    (desc) => (desc.data)
                )
            );
          }
        },
        [images]   
    );
```